Методы кортежей в Python
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть методы кортежей в Python? В книге нашла, что есть методы index() и count(). Подняла документацию, не могу найти где конкретно методы count и index описываются применительно к кортежам. Подскажите, достоверна, ли информация в книге?


Да, достоверна. Кортеж - частный случай последовательности, а все последовательности поддерживают эти два метода. 5.3. Tuples and Sequences, Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.

получается, что там count и index нету. Кстати, в книгах ещё встроенные функции max и min рассматривают относительно кортежей, но вот в документации вижу функцию len(), что она применима.

спасибо огромное за помощь!

@PYTHON_KA Кроме стандартных средств языка есть ещё очень удобный модуль itertools.
https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-itertools.html
